# How to detect any change of element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, bind

i have this html page:

```
     <div style="width: 100%;position: absolute; bottom: 0px; height: 49px;" id="TabBar">
  <ul>
    <li  role='{"type":"tabbar"}' class="itemClickable"><img class="tabIcon" src="/assets/builder/tabIcon.png"    /><br /><label>Home</label></li>
    <li  role='{"type":"tabbar"}' class="itemClickable"><img class="tabIcon " src="/assets/builder/tabIcon.png"   /><br /><label>About</label></li>
    <li  role='{"type":"tabbar"}' class="itemClickable"><img class="tabIcon" src="/assets/builder/tabIcon.png"   /><br /><label>Gallery</label></li>
    <li  role='{"type":"tabbar"}' class="itemClickable"><img class="tabIcon" src="/assets/builder/tabIcon.png"   /><br /><label>Contact-Us</label></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="/assets/ide/add_48.png" id="AddTab"   />
</div>
```

i need to detect ANY change of the 'li' elements.
for example, a change of the label text OR the label color, change of class, change of image and every change that can be.
since its many tags one inside the other, everything i tried did not triggering change of label color.
is there a way to detect this kind of changes WITHOUT specific path like "ul li .item" ?
i want to be able to detect this kind of changes on other elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 solution using Object.observe

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Respond-to-change-with-Object-observe
https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe (polyfill/shim)